# View posts from category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I got stuck at some point. I create a blog and have a question about posts.

My blog.php template displays categories using:

```
    <?php
        $categories = get_categories();
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
           $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
           echo '<a href="'.esc_url( $category_link ).'" title="'.esc_attr($cat->name).'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
        }
    ?>
```

Everything is ok. Displays the categories "inspirations" and "tips".
However, the problem arises when I click on a given category. I want only posts from the selected category to be displayed there. I don't want to use a specific category because I want the administrator to be able to add more categories himself.

I have no idea what to put in my category.php file so that the category knows what posts to display.

My category.php file:

```
<?php 

// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You only showed code for `blog.php` and nothing about `category.php` We can help with code, but we're not telepathic...

Comment: because I don't know exactly what to find there. When I use a regular loop, it shows me posts from all categories .. i will edit my ask for u.

Comment: I believe since you are using `get_category_link`, you can use `have_posts()` and loop with `the_post();`. See this example here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/category.php